# Is there method that you can get all documents from firestore and then use the data inside it?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, native

This is what i have for every user with a UID:
But i want to receive all documents to show in a card. And when they click a button the card disappears and a new one shows with  new data, that data is from a random user.

This is a class to save data to the current user with their UID.

```
    class DatabaseService {

  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({ this.uid });

  final CollectionReference users = Firestore.instance
  .collection("users");

  Future updateUserData(String instagram, String age, String genders) async {
    return await users.document(uid).setData({
      "instagram": instagram,
      "age": age,
      "gender": genders,
    });
  }

  Future updateGender(String genders) async {
    return await users.document(uid).updateData({
      "gender": genders,
    });
  }

    Future updateProfile(String age, String name, String description, String picture) async {
    return await users.document(uid).updateData({
      "age": age,
      "name": name,
      "description": description,
      "picture": picture,
    });
  }

    Future updateAccount(bool account) async {
    return await users.document(uid).updateData({
      "private": account,
    });
  }

  // THIS CAUSES PROBALY THE SPIKES IN READS. CHANGE THIS A BIT

  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      account: snapshot.data["private"],
      instagram: snapshot.data["instagram"],
      gender: snapshot.data["gender"],
      age: snapshot.data["age"],
      description: snapshot.data["description"],
      name: snapshot.data["name"],
      picture: snapshot.data["picture"],
    );
  }


  //get user doc stream
  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return users.document(uid).snapshots()
      .map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a little info about how your firestore data is structured? It would help in diagnosing your problem better.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh i have updated it with what i have now for saving and retrieving data.

Comment: what do you mean by use the data inside it?

Comment: @Ggriffo i have for every user a document with a uniqe UID and in that document are there fields with name, gender, age etc. I want to get a random user and than display the name, gender, age from that random user

Comment: Do you want to display all the users in random order and have them change onClick OR do you want to display one card and have that user change randomly?

Comment: @BrandonPillay i want 1 card with random user, but that card can be swiped and then the same card loads but than with again a different user.